# Memory leak when using fortify static code analyser for unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, fortify

Using `std::unique_ptr` in c++11 in fortify Static Code Analyser is giving me a memory leak.

```
void *httpServerThread(void *arg)
{
  
    std::unique_ptr <int> i(new int(1));
    return NULL;
}
```

Meanwhile, the below code shows no memory leak.

```
void *httpServerThread(void *arg)
{
  
    int * i  = new int(1);
    delete i;
    return NULL;
}
```

Since there is no `std::make_unique`, there is no way to create `std::unique_ptr` without `new`. I am using the 19.2.0 version of fortify -> Fortify_SCA_and_Apps_19.2.0.
Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: The analyzer is wrong, there is no leak in your first example.  Also, FWIW, you can write your own `make_unique` to encapsulate the constrcution.

Comment: Maybe no `make_unique` in C++11 but really, it is time to update to C++17, surely.
See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no memory leak in the shown function. The message is a false positive.

---

> Since there is no std::make_unique, there is no way to create std::unique_ptr without new.

Note that you can write your own `make_unique`. Sure, that function has to use `new`, but nothing else does.